# Check out this error (pointers, C, printf)

Tags: c, pointers, printf, character

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {

   char letters[] = "sjdfhbakshfoweiuh23423";
   char* p;
   int size = sizeof(letters);
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       p = letters[i];
       printf("Address: %p \n", p);
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
       p = letters[i];
       printf("Charachter: %c \n", p);
   }
}
```

Not sure whats going on by when compiled there is an error that says:

```
Warning C4047   '=': 'char *' differs in levels of 
indirection from 'char'
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are try to assign a `char`

```
letters[i]
```

to a `char*`

```
char* p;
```

in your loop:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    p = letters[i];
    printf("Address: %p \n", p);
   }
```

The correct version would look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

    void main() {
    
       char letters[] = "sjdfhbakshfoweiuh23423";
       char p;
       int size = sizeof(letters);
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           p = letters[i];
           printf("Address: %p \n", p);
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           p = letters[i];
           printf("Charachter: %c \n", p);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assign `letters[i]` to `p`, you are assigning a `char` to a `char *`